# The ViewData item that has the key 'message' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, strong-typing

I am trying to implement a MVC application that has a view, controller and view model in order to populate a dropdown list from a database and then use the data for the selected item in a  [HttpPost]. Below is the data in each of the corresponding files:

MessageController.cs

```
public String send_url;
    private msg_cmsEntities smse = new msg_cmsEntities();
public ActionResult Message_Send_Get()
{

    var model = new MessageModel
    {
        MessagesList = smse.Messages
           .Select(c => new SelectListItem
           {
               Value = c.message1,
               Text = c.message1
           })
    };
    return View(model);            
}

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Message_Send_Get(String code, String password, String from, String Message_List, MessageModel message_to_send)
    {
        //If the Model is valid (no errors) then go into this statement
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            WebRequest wrGETURL;

        //This is a string that points to the location of the Web Service 
        string web_service_location = "http://www.google.com?";

        //This initates a new writeable instance of HttpValueCollection
        NameValueCollection query_string = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        //This builds up the query string that will be used for the redirect
        query_string["code"] = code;
        query_string["password"] = password;
        query_string["from"] = from;
        query_string["msg"] = Message_List;

        //This concatinates the web_service_location (String) and query_string (String)
        send_url = web_service_location + query_string.ToString();


        Debug.WriteLine(send_url);

        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(send_url);
    }
    var model = new MessageModel
    {
        MessagesList = smse.Messages
           .Select(c => new SelectListItem
           {
               Value = c.message1,
               Text = c.message1
           })
    };
    return View(message_to_send);
}
```

Message_Send_Get.aspx(The View):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Message_Send.Models.MessageModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Message_Send_Get
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Message_Send_Get</h2>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fields</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.code) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.code) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.code) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.password) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.password) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.from) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.from) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.from) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.message) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.message, Model.MessagesList)%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.message) %>
            </div>               

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>

    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

MessageModels.cs

```
public class MessageModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a code for this service!!")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [DisplayName("Code")]
        public string code { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A password is required for the service!!")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [DisplayName("Password")]
        public string password { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter the 'From' information!!")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [DisplayName("Message From")]
        public string sms_from { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Send Message")]
        public string message { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MessagesList { get; set; }
    }
```

When using this I get the error in the title, can someone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: This all looks good to me...have you tried stepping through it to find exactly where the error is occurring?  Is it in your GET or POST actions?  Is it in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your POST controller action you seem to be instantiating some model variable that you do nothing with it. You still `return View(message_to_send);` and of course this `message_to_send` variable doesn't have its `MessagesList` property assigned. Also why are you repeating all action arguments when they are already present in your view model?

Here's how I would suggest you improve your code (I have put some Warnings as comments in the code):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Message_Send_Get(MessageModel message_to_send)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        WebRequest wrGETURL;

        //This is a string that points to the location of the Web Service 
        string web_service_location = "http://www.google.com?";

        //This initates a new writeable instance of HttpValueCollection
        NameValueCollection query_string = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        //This builds up the query string that will be used for the redirect
        query_string["code"] = message_to_send.code;
        query_string["password"] = message_to_send.password;
        query_string["from"] = message_to_send.sms_from;

        // Warning: you seem to have used some Message_List argument in your action
        // but there's no corresponding input field in the view or in the model
        // maybe you want to add some
        // query_string["msg"] = message_to_send.sms_from.msg;

        //This concatinates the web_service_location (String) and query_string (String)
        send_url = web_service_location + query_string.ToString();

        Debug.WriteLine(send_url);

        // Warning: Here you only created the request but never sent it
        // I guess you will have to complete the code .....
        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(send_url);
    }

    // since we want to redisplay the same view we need to reassign the
    // MessagesList property used by the dropdown because in HTML a dropdown
    // sends only the selected value when the form is submitted and not the entire
    // list of options
    message_to_send.MessagesList = smse.Messages
       .Select(c => new SelectListItem
       {
           Value = c.message1,
           Text = c.message1
       });
    return View(message_to_send);
}
```

Small remark: in your view you seem to be using some `from` property of your model: `<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.from) %>` but such property doesn't exist in the model you have shown. Maybe you meant `sms_from`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help with the code :-) i realise there was some junk code in there and this was due to me trying so many ways around this issue lol! You code helped me along the way except i am still getting this error "The ViewData item that has the key 'message' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'." This appears to be occuring on line "<%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.message, Model.MessagesList)%>" of my View and I think this is related to my view model. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you see that I return `return View(message_to_send);`? Also did you see that I set the `message_to_send.MessagesList` property just before returning? Did you do the same thing? In your code you seem to have instantiated some `model` variable that was never used. I have tested the code and it worked fine. Try removing all the junk (everything inside the ModelState.IsValid condition for the moment) to ensure that the code works.